# Flexbox prevent shrink on Mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

I have a div which contains some divs of `.quality` a div of `#infinite` and a `#title` div. The number of `.quality` divs may change depending on the available qualities. The `#title` div should fit in the remaining space and be cut off if there is no space but it can never shrink the other divs.

This works fine in desktop but it doesn't work on iOS in Safari, Chrome and Firefox.

The first picture is taken from Firefox on desktop and bottom picture is taken on Safari on iOS 9.2.1

How can I prevent the `.quality` divs from shrinking?

**Demo:** http://beta.kida.al/theheartwantswhatitwants

```
<div id="title_quality">
    <div id="quality">
        <div style="display: inline-block;" id="hd720" class="quality">720p</div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;" id="hd1080" class="quality">1080p</div>
        <div id="hd1440" class="quality" style="display: none">1440p</div>
        <div id="hd2160" class="quality" style="display: none">2160p</div>
        <div style="display: block;" id="infinite" class="quality uninfinite">∞</div>
    </div>
    <div id="title">the heart wants what it wants, selena gomez</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title_quality {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #f8008c;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#quality {
    display: flex;
}

.quality {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: 11px/40px "quicksand";
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #f8008c;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 4px 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
}

#title {
    font: 14px/48px "quicksand";
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image: Desktop]

[image: Safari iOS]

Comment: Have you tried `flex-shrink: 0` on `.quality` divs?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

added `#quality {flex-shrink: 0}` and worked.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Didn't notice that `#quality` was also a flex item. My bad. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding `flex-shrink:0` to your `.quality` divs like so:

**CSS**

```
.quality {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font: 11px/40px "quicksand";
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #f8008c;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 4px 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in;
    flex-shrink:0; /* <------- */
}
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/b8ycrgfa/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't work it makes it worse. The title goes more on the left than before.